# Django Form Add user from a specific group

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I'm new with Django.

There is my model:

```
class Classe(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    titulaire = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='titulaire', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
```

In a form, I would like add the "titulaire" field and select user from a specific group.

I'll tried something like that.

```
class ModifyClasse(ModelForm):
  class Meta:
      model = Classe
      fields = ['title' , 'year', 'titulaire', 'cotitulaire']
      def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        qs = User.objects.filter(groups__name__in=['Profs'])
        titulaire = kwargs.pop('qs', None)
        super(ModifyClasse, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        del self.fields['titulaire']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`ModelChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField) in your `__init__` so:

```
self.fields["titulaire"] = forms.ModelChoiceField(query=User.objects.filter(groups__name__in=['Profs']), empty_text="Select")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also modify your `__init__` method in `ModifyClasse` form to set the queryset of the `titulaire` field to only include users in the desired group so:

```py
class ModifyClasse(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Classe
        fields = ['title', 'titulaire']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ModifyClasse, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['titulaire'].queryset = User.objects.filter(groups__name='Profs')
```